# Conditional linking in Makefile

Tags: makefile, linker, conditional-statements

In my Makefile, I want to link to a library only if it is installed on the machine. So, for example if the library is `hwloc`, I want to do the following:

```
xfoo : foo.o
   if (hwloc installed)
      gcc foo.o -o $@ -lhwloc
   else
      gcc foo.o -o $@
```

Is there anyway to do something like this? i.e. Is it possible to check if a specific library is installed and use that as a condition in a Makefile?

Comment: I can't understand the usage model - suppose heloc isn't installed on the machine, which entity will resolve its "referenced" symbols?

Comment: Those referenced symbols will be disabled using pre-processor. So, foo.o is not exactly the same for both cases. Sorry for the misunderstanding from the short example.

Comment: An alternative worth considering is letting the user configure if/how they want to link hwloc using a simple variable at the top of your Makefile.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the wrong answer:

```
xfoo : foo.o
   if (hwloc installed); then gcc foo.o -o $@ -lhwloc; else gcc foo.o -o $@; fi
```

Commands executed from a Makefile do not have to be just simple, single commands. Anything that a shell can execute, can be invoked from a Makefile. Including an entire script, sandwiched into one line.

Here's the right answer:

However, the above approach is the wrong one. You will find that many free software packages do this kind of thing all the time: conditionally link in a library, if it's available.

But the way that it's done is by running a separate `configure` script, before running make. Go grab the source tarball to a random free software package, of your choosing, and read the installation instructions. They will all tell you to run the `configure` script first, before running `make`.

A crushing majority of free software packages use the GNU toolchain to create their build system -- the `configure` script, and the `Makefile`. The GNU toolchain consists of `autoconf` and `automake` tools (also `libtool` in many cases). Go Google these, for more information.

There are also a few other, less popular toolchains, but the GNU toolchain is the most frequently one used, for this sort of a thing. So, to do something along the lines of what you're trying to do, the way this gets typically done is:

In the `configure.ac` file:

```
AC_CHECK_LIB(hwloc,some_function_in_the_hwloc_library,[LINK_HWLOC=-lhwloc])
AC_SUBST(LINK_HWLOC)
```

In the `Makefile.am` file:

```
hwloc_LDADD=@LINK_HWLOC@
```

That's it. That's the way this is done the countless number of times most free software packages need to do this exact same thing. `autoconf` and `automake` will take care of writing the shell script and the makefile, that implements this.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have access to a Linux machine at the moment so pardon me my answer will be untested.

I will respectfully disagree with both of my predecessors.

First, using autotools to amend an existing Makefile is a bad idea.  Autotools are made to avoid worrying about creating a good Makefile in a simple use case.  It's as if OP asked "How to change `+` to `-` in my Python script" and the answer was "write a shell script to modify the script,  save it in temporary file and execute the file"

Second answer, why do something manually when it can be painlessly done automatically?

So, IMHO the correct answer is, this is the exact use case for `$(wildcard)`:

```
xfoo: foo.o $(wildcard libhwloc.a) 
    gcc $(patsubst lib%.a, -l%, $^) -o $@
```

Note:  the library is installed or not ahead of time but *not* to be made during the build.

Comment: Could you please explain how this would work? I am not familiar with `$(wildcard)`. And yes. The library is installed or not, prior to this build.

Comment: @Rakib I am sorry... Please don't be offended but, you now have to go and read the manual, about how the functions `wildcard` and `patsubst` work.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to get involved with the autotools/etc. for this (which while a reasonable solution is also reasonable to want to avoid for something this simple) and you don't want to have to play guessing games about where people may or may not have this `hwloc` library installed then the best you can do is to let people turn the feature on manually.

Use three (or four) make variables. `USE_HWLOC`, `HWLOC_LDLIBS`, `HWLOC_CFLAGS` and possibly `HWLOC_LDFLAGS`.

Then when `USE_HWLOC` is defined you link against the library and use the other three variables in case they have also been set.

```
ifdef USE_HWLOC
HWLOC:=-lhwloc
else
HWLOC:=
HWLOC_LDLIBS:=
HWLOC_LDFLAGS:=
HWLOC_CFLAGS:=
endif

xfoo : foo.o
   gcc foo.o -o $@ $(HWLOC_LDLIBS) $(HWLOC)
```